# Using Jersey 2.x client, how can I read from an InputStream while the server is still writing to its OutputStream?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

We recently upgraded from Jersey 1.x to 2.x and most of the migration went smoothly.  There's one snag though.

In 1.x, the following code would let us grab the InputStream while the server was still writing to its respective OutputStream:

```
final ClientResponse response = webResource
    .accept(acceptHeader)
    .get(ClientResponse.class);
final InputStream stream = response.getEntity(InputStream.class);
/* Process the stream, waiting if necessary */
```

We are using this as a sort of server-send event (before we found out about sse), but a similar and more common problem would be downloading a large file.  The Jersey 2.x code looks like:

```
final Response response = webTarget
    .request()
    .accept(acceptHeader)
    .get();    /* debug shows this call hanging */
final InputStream stream = response.getEntity(InputStream.class);
/* Process the stream, waiting if necessary */
```

The get() method hangs because the server never closes the connection.  Fortunately in our case, the server is just waiting for "events" to send to the client, but if the client were downloading say a 64 GB file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was on the server side.

In Jersey 1.x, the server was not buffering the response (or we had overridden that behavior and forgotten).  The solution was to set the property `jersey.config.contentLength.buffer` to `0`.  This prevented the server from buffering, and the code listed in this question worked without modification.